# Group the result of an already grouped query sql/laravel

Tags: laravel

Hello everyone this is my first post and after giving this a lot of work my head just doesn't want to cooperate anymore, I've searched online for answers but can't find related cases, I am working in laravel 5.2 with a query, said query is to get the progress on items and count the items that share the same progress to display in a pie chart.

Relations are as follows:

I have 3 tables:

1. Items
2. Steps to complete (each one has a percentage).
3. Progress of each item per step (Completed true or false)

Right now I have this code

```
table('items as i')
        ->join('items_sectors as is', 'i.sector_id', '=', 'is.id')
        ->join('sectors_steps_progress as stp', 'i.id', '=', 'stp.item_id')
        ->join('sectors_steps as cs', 'stp.step_id', '=', 'cs.id')
        ->where('stp.completed', true)
        ->selectRaw('count(distinct i.id) as count, CONCAT(sum(cs.percentage), "%") as percentage')
        ->groupBy('stp.completed', 'i.id');
```

And this with some testing data outputs

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => {#2042 ▼
    +"count": 1
    +"percentage": "50%"
  }
  1 => {#2043 ▼
    +"count": 1
    +"percentage": "100%"
  }
  2 => {#2044 ▼
    +"count": 1
    +"percentage": "100%"
  }
]
```

What I want is to now join all the matchings "percentage" and count them so it would end up like:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => {#2042 ▼
    +"count": 1
    +"label": "50%"
  }
  1 => {#2043 ▼
    +"count": 2
    +"label": "100%"
  }
]
```

Thanks a lot if anyone can help me with this, I'm still trying to figure it out :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if result is not a collection convert it to a collection and apply the code below

```
 $result = $array->groupBy("percentage")
        ->map(function($q){
            $newArray['count'] = count($q);
            $newArray['percentage'] = $q[0]['percentage'];

            return $newArray;
        })->values();

return $result;
```

Hope it helps.